# add actionbar button with navigation drawer?

Tags: android, button, android-actionbar, drawer

i am having this problem: i'm working with the actionbar navigation drawer, but i want to add aditionally a button to the menu bar, something like these buttons:
http://screenshots.en.sftcdn.net/blog/en/2013/06/notifications-b.png

this is my xml file:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout
     android:id="@+id/content_frame"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" />
     <!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView
     android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
     android:layout_width="240dp"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_gravity="start"
     android:background="#111"
     android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
     android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
     android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

so, i know that adding a buttons is something like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"  />
</menu>
```

but i still don't know how to fit both parts, can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Activity_Main, or whatever is your main activity, you call:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.YOUR_MENU, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
}
```

YOUR_MENU is the options menu/actionbar you want.

If you want to add another button, or individualize the buttons according to the specific fragment inside the frame_layout/drawer layout, then in your fragment, put add this in the onCreateView:

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

This tells the activity that you are going to alter the options menu.

Then:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.YOUR_NEW_MENU, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
}
```

Whatever items YOUR_NEW_MENU has will be added to the optionsmenu/actionbar.

Answer (score 1):

Did you map this Menu Item to your activity? If not you need to override `onCreateOptionsMenu` in your activity and inflate it there.

You can read this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) on menus.